# How to get the position of the string in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to know why `array_search()` is not able to get the position of the string in the following array

**MY Code**

```
$row1['infopropiedades'] ="Dirección<>#Fotos<>SALTEST.ANUNCIO.IMAGENES.IMAGEN.IMAGEN_URL#Fotos Description<>SALTEST.ANUNCIO.DESCRIPCION#Map<>#Youtube URL<>#Titulo<>SALTEST.ANUNCIO.TITULO#Descripción<>SALTEST.ANUNCIO.DESCRIPCION#Detalles específicos<>#Telefono<>SALTEST.ANUNCIO.TELEFONO#Celular<>SALTEST.ANUNCIO.TELEFONO#Terreno<>SALTEST.ANUNCIO.TERRENO#Construcción<>SALTEST.ANUNCIO.CONSTRUCCION#Venta<>SALTEST.ANUNCIO.MONEDA#Alquiler<>";

$x= explode("#",$row1['infopropiedades']);
        print_r($x);
        echo $key = array_search('Fotos Description', $x);
        if($key!=0)
        {
        $v = explode('<>',$x[$key]);
        echo $Fotos_Description = $v[1];
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Because `Fotos Description` is not in the array.  `Fotos Description<>SALTEST.ANUNCIO.DESCRIPCION` is.

Comment: 1. What is your goal with this code? 2. You don't have an element with `Fotos Description`

Comment: Actually I am trying to save the string that is related with Fotos Description in the variable $Fotos_Description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_search()` is looking for the exact string not a partial match.  Here is a quick way to get it:

```
preg_match('/#Fotos Description<>([^#]+)#/', $row1['infopropiedades'], $v);
echo $Fotos_Description = $v[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

[preg_grep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) was made for searching arrays and will return the results in an array.  A combination of `key()` and `preg_grep()` will return the key you are looking for.

```
echo $key = key(preg_grep("/^Fotos Description.*/", $x));
```

As others pointed out, array_search only matches if the value is equal.

Comment: I love `preg_grep` but the title here is misleading.  They don't really want the position, they want a string after a string.

Comment: @AbraCadaver, yes, I didn't read into the code as much as you did.  Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `needle` is only a part of the whole haystack that each array element contains, `array_search` won't work. You can loop through all the values and find what you are looking for

```
   foreach($x as $key=>$haystack)
   {
       if(stristr($haystack,'Fotos Description')!==FALSE)
       {
           $v = explode('<>',$haystack);
            echo $Fotos_Description = $v[1];   
       }
   }
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/310190)**

Answer (score 1):

Because array_search just searches for an exact match. So you have to iterate over the whole array and check if the value has this string

or you could use array_filter with a custom callback function for example